# How to extract digits (in binary) from binary number in ASM (pic16f628a) or C, C++

Tags: assembly, pic

I need to extract the digits from a binary number.

For example, I have 62 number in decimal and the two digits are 6 and 2. In binary:

```
62 = 00111110  --> 8 bit value

digit 6 = 0110 --> 4 bit value
digit 2 = 0010 --> 4 bit value
```

I need an algorithm to extract the digits and I'm using the asm for pic16f628a microcontroller.

There is an example of I want:

```
ORG     0x00
MOVLW   B'00111110' ; 62
MOVWF   0X30
; ... CODE TO EXTRACT THE DIGITS FROM VALUE IN REGISTER 0X30
; The register 0X31 is loaded with '00000110' (digit 6)
; The register 0X32 is loaded with '00000010' (digit 2)
```

But it can also be with C or C ++.

Comment: For x of 2 digits, can you use this? ((x/10)<<4)|((x%10))

Comment: [this link](https://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf) has all 8086 assembly instructions, I think AAA instruction will do the work

Comment: @MohamedAkram: PIC is a different architecture from 8086.  Also, I don't think AAA is useful for the general case, you'd need AAM (division) to separate a number into 2 decimal digits.

Comment: @Ignactior: to get *decimal* digits out, you need to divide and modulo by 10.  You might implement that with a bit-manipulation trick, but there's nothing really efficient like there would be to get the binary digits or the hex digits.

Comment: For numbers from 0..99 you can use lookup table hex to dec.